# Randomly occurring issue: 'Unable to resolve service for type (...)' with Hangfire

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, hangfire

I encountered a strange issue with Hangfire. I'm getting sometimes (totally randomly) error about Unable to resolve service for type 'AW.Services.Interfaces.ISmsService' while attempting to activate 'AW.Services.Jobs.SendSmsJob'. When I click requeue on dashboard on this failed job it either fails again or finish with success. It happens really randomly and I don't have any idea what is happening.

I have registered my interface in IoC of course like this: `services.AddTransient<ISmsService, SmsService>();`.

I'm using the following packages versions:

- .NET Core 3.1
- Hangfire v1.7.9
- Hangfire.AspNetCore v1.7.9
- Hangfire.Console v1.4.2
- Hangfire.PostgreSql v1.6.4.1

My hangfire's configuration in startup.cs is the following:

```cs
services.AddHangfire(config =>
{
    config.UsePostgreSqlStorage(Configuration["AW_API_DB_CONNECTIONSTRING"]);
    config.UseConsole();
});
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSerializerSettings
(
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    }
);

(...)

app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions
{
       WorkerCount = backgroundProcessingWorkersCount
});

app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions
{
    WorkerCount = backgroundProcessingWorkersCount,
    Queues = new[] { JobQueueTypes.Transactions }
});
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/dashboard", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] { new AgriWalletDashboardAuthFilter() },
    I
```

Below I've copied the entire log from hangfire's dashboard:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'AW.Services.Interfaces.ISmsService' while attempting to activate 'AW.Services.Jobs.SendSmsJob'. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AW.Services.Interfaces.ISmsService' while attempting to activate 'AW.Services.Jobs.SendSmsJob'. at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider) at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters) at
>   Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext
>   context) 
>   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0() 
>   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter
>   filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func1 continuation  at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter
>   filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func1 continuation) at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 filters) at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
>   at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context,
>   IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)

Answer (score 1):

Migration from netcore2 to netcore3 may cause issues with Dependency Injection. Please verify the project Program.cs and Startup.cs classes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Indeed, it caused the problem :)